# Link only working if opened in new tab?

Tags: html, tabs, hyperlink

I have an  tag on a page that redirects to the same page if left clicked, but the correct page if right click, new tabbed.  If you hover over the link or copy it, it displays the proper URL.  Is there any known reason for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code would be helpful...

Comment: Some JavaScript magic

Comment: Not only we need to see the code - but also which type of browser

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you forgot the `http://` or other protocol before the web address.

If you have an anchor link on your webpage for example `http://mysite.com/article/`

```
<a href='myothersite.com'>Other Site</a>
```

If you click on the link without opening it in a new tab the browser thinks that it's a subdirectory on the current website and it sends you to 
`http://mysite.com/article/myothersite.com`

You have to add a protocol before the web address, for example:

```
<a href='http://myothersite.com'>Other Site</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that's not it.  We are, in fact, trying to send it to a subdirectory.  I will get my code on here, I was hoping it was something common because I'm going to really have to work to condense it to get it fittable here.

Comment: Worked for me. I had spent hours in Chrome developer tools trying to figure this out. Thanks